# Join when a date is within a date range ( Kusto / KQL / Azure Data Explorer )

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

In KQL, how can you add criteria for a join?  For example, the query below shows a join.  I only want to join rows when the 'code' column is equal and when 'date' is between StartDate and EndDate.  I know this is possible in SQL but have not seen a working example in KQL.

Please keep in mind that the example below is not the actual dataset.  I know I can achieve the desired result by filtering post join; however, this is not possible with the actual dataset due to the size of table B.  When I try to filter post join, I run out of memory (runaway query).

```
let A = datatable(Code:string, StartDate:string, EndDate:string, Rate:string)[
'EUR', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-15', '1.5',
'EUR', '2020-01-15', '2020-01-31', '1.7',
'YEN', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-15', '2.1',
'YEN', '2020-01-15', '2020-01-31', '1.9'];
let B = datatable(Key:string, Code:string, Date:string)[
'1', 'EUR', '2020-01-02', 
'2', 'EUR', '2020-01-16', 
'3', 'EUR', '2020-01-13', 
'4', 'EUR', '2020-01-27', 
'5', 'YEN', '2020-01-03', 
'6', 'YEN', '2020-01-03', ];
A | join kind=inner B on Code 
| project-away *1, StartDate, EndDate
| summarize by Key, Date, Code, Rate
```

**Current Result**

```
Key Date        Code    Rate
1   2020-01-02  EUR     1.7
1   2020-01-02  EUR     1.5
2   2020-01-16  EUR     1.7
2   2020-01-16  EUR     1.5
3   2020-01-13  EUR     1.7
3   2020-01-13  EUR     1.5
4   2020-01-27  EUR     1.7
4   2020-01-27  EUR     1.5
5   2020-01-03  YEN     1.9
5   2020-01-03  YEN     2.1
6   2020-01-03  YEN     1.9
6   2020-01-03  YEN     2.1
```

**Expected Result**

```
Key Date        Code    Rate
1   2020-01-02  EUR     1.5
2   2020-01-16  EUR     1.7
3   2020-01-13  EUR     1.5
4   2020-01-27  EUR     1.7
5   2020-01-03  YEN     2.1
6   2020-01-03  YEN     2.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a filter after the join and use the [Time window join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/join-timewindow) technique

```
let lookupWindow = 1d;
let A = datatable(Code:string, StartDate:datetime , EndDate:datetime , Rate:string)[
'EUR', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-15', '1.5',
'EUR', '2020-01-15', '2020-01-31', '1.7',
'YEN', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-15', '2.1',
'YEN', '2020-01-15', '2020-01-31', '1.9'];
let B = datatable(Key:string, Code:string, Date:datetime )[
'1', 'EUR', '2020-01-02', 
'2', 'EUR', '2020-01-16', 
'3', 'EUR', '2020-01-13', 
'4', 'EUR', '2020-01-27', 
'5', 'YEN', '2020-01-03', 
'6', 'YEN', '2020-01-03', ];
A 
| extend TimeKey = range(bin(StartDate, lookupWindow), bin(EndDate,lookupWindow), lookupWindow)
| mv-expand TimeKey to typeof(datetime)
| join kind=inner (B 
    | extend TimeKey = bin(Date, 1d)
) on Code,TimeKey
| where Date between (StartDate .. EndDate)
| project-away  StartDate, EndDate, TimeKey*, Code1
```

| Code | Rate | Key | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EUR | 1.5 | 1 | 2020-01-02 00:00:00.0000000 |
| EUR | 1.5 | 3 | 2020-01-13 00:00:00.0000000 |
| EUR | 1.7 | 2 | 2020-01-16 00:00:00.0000000 |
| EUR | 1.7 | 4 | 2020-01-27 00:00:00.0000000 |
| YEN | 2.1 | 5 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00.0000000 |
| YEN | 2.1 | 6 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00.0000000 |

Comment: @Averna, as stated in the original question:

_"I know I can achieve the desired result by filtering post join; however, this is not possible with the actual dataset due to the size of table B"_

I am looking for a way to add the filters as conditions to the join.

Comment: To be clear, I am trying to do something like this:

```A  |  join kind=inner B on Code and Date between (StartDate .. EndDate)```

Comment: Sorry - I missed it. I updated the example to include an optimization technique called Time window join. Would be interesting to see if it will work better for you. Please note that providing shuffle key hint for the "code" column might help so please try first without and then add it and compare.

Comment: that worked thank you!